# How do I reduce duplication for RSpec error testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, refactoring

Greetings and thanks for anyone tuning in.

I've got a method that may generate errors and I've got some special logic that runs when an error happens and before another exception gets re-raised.

example:

```
def some_cool_method
 error_prone_logic

 rescue StandardError => e
   logging_methods
   
   error_handling

   raise SpecificException.new
end
```

spec setup:

I am making a stub for one of the entities that are used in the `error_prone_logic` and make it throw an exception like this:

```
    before do
      allow(some_entity_double).to receive(:work).and_raise(StandardError, 'RIP')
    end
```

My issue is that when I want to test the logic that runs after an error happens and I want to separate the specs I produce code that has to always has to test for the exception:

```
    it 'raises explicit error' do
      expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)
    end

    it 'logs the error' do
      expect(logger).to receive(:error)

      expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)
    end

    it 'does error handling' do
      expect(ErrorHandler).to receive(:handle)

      expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)
    end
```

If the
`expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)` at the end of each case is missing the - test suite fails to run.

So my question is:

Is there a way to set this up so that I only have one spec for `expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)` and the rest are only asserting what they need to assert?

Comment: Can't you just rescue `SpecificException` instead of using `.to raise_error`? eg. `begin; do_the_thing; rescue  SpecificException; expect(ErrorHandler).to receive(:handle); end`.

Comment: In this case the process can't continue and I don't want my client to be testing the result of the method, so rescuing is not an option.

The goal is to add visibility to the issue and let it bubble up.

Comment: But this is exactly the same as what `expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)` does. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/main/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/raise_error.rb#L48

Comment: The code under test will still be halted. You're just rescuing the exception when it bubbles up to the test.

Comment: @max Alright, I think I understand the confusion. I've added a section where I'm providing the setup code for my specs. I think this missing part might have misrepresented the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method should be allowed to raise SpecificException just catch the error as it bubbles up to the test.

```
before 
  some_cool_method
  rescue SpecificException
end 

it 'logs the error' do
  expect(logger).to receive(:error)
end

it 'does error handling' do
  expect(ErrorHandler).to receive(:handle)
end
```

This is the exact same thing that happens when you `expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)` but without creating an expectation.

Note that [the explicit use of subject in RSpec is considered a code smell](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/).

Answer (score 1):

What's about error raising incapsulation into the method?

```
def some_cool_method
 error_prone_logic

rescue StandardError
  logging_methods
   
  error_handling

  raise_error
end
```

In this case you can mock it everywhere except error raising test

```
before
  allow(some_cool_entity).to receive(:raise_error)
end

it 'raises explicit error' do
  allow(some_cool_entity).to receive(:raise_error).and_call_original

  expect { subject }.to raise_error(SpecificException)
end

it 'logs the error' do
  expect(logger).to receive(:error)
end

it 'does error handling' do
  expect(ErrorHandler).to receive(:handle)
end
```